# How can I write a Gazebo Plug-in on MAC OS?

Tags: gazebo-ignition, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone, I'm wondering if it's possible to write a Gazebo plug-in on MAC OS, so this means without ROS. Right now, I'm using the PX4 with Gazebo source and if I try to compile the already existing plug-ins I have multiple errors.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28509/how-can-i-write-a-gazebo-plug-in-on-mac-os?/) by [FM-SEAL](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111242/fm-seal/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes it's possible to develop plugins for Gazebo on macOS (either Intel or arm64). You will need a source build of Gazebo Garden and possibly Ogre2 if you are planning on developing visual plugins.

An example of a plugin which has been developed on macOS is the latest version of the ArduPilot/ardupilot_gazebo plugin where the addition of the SITL_JSON backend was primarily developed on macOS.

---

Originally posted by [srmainwaring](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29010/srmainwaring/) with karma: 61 on 2022-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FM-SEAL](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111242/fm-seal/) on 2023-04-19**:
Thank you!